# jQuery closest not working on dynamically added table row

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm adding table rows dynamically with a button "Add New Line".  When clicked, this fires off a jQuery event which creates a new table row containing form fields.  The form fields allow numeric values only.

When a value gets entered into the field, it calculates VAT and Line Total amounts.  These totals then get appended to the `closest()` table row `<tr>`.

The code works fine for the first row.  As soon as a new row is added, the code stops working and values are calculated for the second row.

I believe this has something to do with the fact the rows (and form fields) are dynamically created by jQuery and injected into the page, so `closest()` cant't find them.

Whats the solution to this?

Thanks in advance.

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var counter = 2;

    $("#addRow").on("click", function () 
    {
        var newRow = $("<tr>");
        var cols = "";

        cols += '<td>' + counter + '</td>';
        cols += '<td><textarea class="form-control" name="description[' + counter + ']"></textarea></td>';
        cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control line-quantity" name="quantity[' + counter + ']" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"></td>';
        cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control line-price" name="unit_price[' + counter + ']" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"></td>';
        cols += '<td class="line_vat">£0.00</td>';
        cols += '<td class="line_total">£0.00</td>';
        cols += '<td><input type="button" class="ibtnDel btn btn-md btn-danger"  value="Delete"></td>';
        newRow.append(cols);
        $("table.table-striped").append(newRow);
        counter++;
    });

    $("table.table-striped").on("click", ".ibtnDel", function (event) 
    {
        $(this).closest("tr").remove();
        counter -= 1
    });

    // Update line vat & subtotal
    $(".line-quantity, .line-price").on("blur", function (event)
    {
        var line_qty = 0;
        var line_price = 0;
        var line_subtotal = '0.00';
        var vat = '0.00';
        var line_total = '0.00';

        line_qty = $(this).closest('#quote_table').find('input.line-quantity').val();
        line_price = $(this).closest('#quote_table').find('input.line-price').val();

        // calculate total line price
        line_subtotal = line_price*line_qty;

        // Calculate VAT
        vat = line_subtotal*1.2-line_subtotal;

        // Line total
        line_total = line_subtotal+vat;
        
        // Update view with totals
        $(this).closest('tr').find('td.line_vat').html(vat.toLocaleString('en-US', {style: 'currency',currency: 'GBP'}));
        $(this).closest('tr').find('td.line_total').html(line_total.toLocaleString('en-US', {style: 'currency',currency: 'GBP'}));

        // Calculate totals at end of table

    });
});

function isNumberKey(evt){
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
    return false;
    return true;
}
```

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="{{ url('cp/quotes/create') }}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="form-group">
      @if($contacts->isEmpty())
      <a href="/cp/contacts/create">Create first contact</a>
      @else
      <label for="contact">Contact</label>
      <!-- Get the selected contact and fetch properties -->
      <select class="form-control selectpicker show-tick" data-live-search="true" id="contact" name="contact" data-live-search-placeholder="Find contact...">
        <option value="">Select a contact...</option>
      @foreach($contacts as $contact)
        <option data-tokens="{{ $contact->id }}" value="{{ $contact->id }}">{{ $contact->contact_name }} ({{ $contact->first_name }} {{ $contact->last_name }})</option>
      @endforeach
      </select>
      <!-- List contact properties -->
      <div class="btn-group-vertical property_list" role="group" aria-label="Property" id="property_list"></div>
      @endif
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="raised_date">
       Date
      </label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-addon">
          <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>  
        </div>
        <input class="form-control" id="raised_date" name="raised_date" type="text"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="raised_date">
       Expiry Date
      </label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-addon">
          <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>  
        </div>
        <input class="form-control" id="expiry_date" name="expiry_date" type="text"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <table class="table table-striped" id="quote_table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Item #</th>
          <th scope="col">Description</th>
          <th scope="col">Quantity</th>
          <th scope="col">Unit Price</th>
          <th scope="col">VAT</th>
          <th scope="col">Amount</th>
          <th scope="col"></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td><textarea class="form-control" name="description[]"></textarea></td>
          <td><input class="form-control line-quantity" name="quantity[]" type="text" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"></td>
          <td><input class="form-control line-price" name="unit_price[]" type="text" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"></td>
          <td class="line_vat">£0.00</td>
          <td class="line_total">£0.00</td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="5" class="text-end">Subtotal</td>
          <td colspan="2" class="subtotal">£0.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="5" class="text-end h3">Total</td>
          <td colspan="2" class="total h3">£0.00</td>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
    <a class="btn btn-warning addRow" href="#" id="addRow">Add Line +</a>
    <div class="form-group">
      <br /><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save Quote</button>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Application screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code in my own development environment and found that the `onblur` functionality does not work properly for new dynamic added rows in table. So I searched the web and found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements) that could solve your problem. After that I changed your **HTML** and **JavaScript** codes as follows:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    var counter = 2;

    $("#addRow").on("click", function ()
    {
        var newRow = $("<tr>");
        var cols = "";

        cols += '<td>' + counter + '</td>';
        cols += '<td><textarea class="form-control" name="description[' + counter + ']"></textarea></td>';
        cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control line-quantity" name="quantity[' + counter + ']" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"></td>';
        cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control line-price" name="unit_price[' + counter + ']" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"></td>';
        cols += '<td class="line_vat">£0.00</td>';
        cols += '<td class="line_total">£0.00</td>';
        cols += '<td><input type="button" class="ibtnDel btn btn-md btn-danger"  value="Delete"></td>';
        newRow.append(cols);
        $("table.table-striped").append(newRow);
        counter++;
    });

    $("table.table-striped").on("click", ".ibtnDel", function (event)
    {
        $(this).closest("tr").remove();
        /* -------------------------------------- */
        /* commenting decreasing "counter" for better functionality after deleting rows */
        /* -------------------------------------- */
        // counter -= 1
    });

    /* -------------------------------------- */
    /* converting line_qty and line_price to arrays to not have conflict between rows */
    /* -------------------------------------- */
    var line_qty = [0];
    var line_price = [0];

    /* -------------------------------------- */
    /* change "blur" event call according to other stack-overflow question for handling dynamically created DOM */
    /* -------------------------------------- */
    $("#quote_table").on("blur", ".line-quantity, .line-price", function () {
        console.log($(this));

        var line_subtotal = '0.00';
        var vat = '0.00';
        var line_total = '0.00';
        /* -------------------------------------- */
        /* using name "attr" to understand which index of "line_qty" and "line_price" arrays must be changed */
        /* -------------------------------------- */
        let indexBrackets = $(this).attr("name").indexOf("[") + 1;
        let rowNum = $(this).attr("name").substr(indexBrackets, 1)

        /* -------------------------------------- */
        /* using "jQuery hasClass()" method to find which input in each row has blur event */
        /* -------------------------------------- */
        if ($(this).hasClass("line-quantity")) {
                line_qty[rowNum-1] = $(this).val();
        }

        console.log(line_qty);

        if ($(this).hasClass("line-price")) {
            line_price[rowNum-1] = $(this).val();
        }

        console.log(line_price);


        // calculate total line price
        /* -------------------------------------- */
        /* using arrays to calculate final values */
        /* -------------------------------------- */
        line_subtotal = line_price[rowNum-1]*line_qty[rowNum-1];

        // Calculate VAT
        vat = line_subtotal*1.2-line_subtotal;

        // Line total
        line_total = line_subtotal+vat;
        console.log(line_total);

        // Update view with totals
        $(this).closest('tr').find('td.line_vat').html(vat.toLocaleString('en-US', {style: 'currency',currency: 'GBP'}));
        $(this).closest('tr').find('td.line_total').html(line_total.toLocaleString('en-US', {style: 'currency',currency: 'GBP'}));

        // Calculate totals at end of table
    });

});

function isNumberKey(evt){
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<form method="post" action="{{ url('cp/quotes/create') }}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="form-group">
        @if($contacts->isEmpty())
        <a href="/cp/contacts/create">Create first contact</a>
        @else
        <label for="contact">Contact</label>
        <!-- Get the selected contact and fetch properties -->
        <select class="form-control selectpicker show-tick" data-live-search="true" id="contact" name="contact" data-live-search-placeholder="Find contact...">
            <option value="">Select a contact...</option>
            @foreach($contacts as $contact)
            <option data-tokens="{{ $contact->id }}" value="{{ $contact->id }}">{{ $contact->contact_name }} ({{ $contact->first_name }} {{ $contact->last_name }})</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
        <!-- List contact properties -->
        <div class="btn-group-vertical property_list" role="group" aria-label="Property" id="property_list"></div>
        @endif
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="raised_date">
            Date
        </label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
            </div>
            <input class="form-control" id="raised_date" name="raised_date" type="text"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="raised_date">
            Expiry Date
        </label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
            </div>
            <input class="form-control" id="expiry_date" name="expiry_date" type="text"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <table class="table table-striped" id="quote_table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Item #</th>
            <th scope="col">Description</th>
            <th scope="col">Quantity</th>
            <th scope="col">Unit Price</th>
            <th scope="col">VAT</th>
            <th scope="col">Amount</th>
            <th scope="col"></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td><textarea class="form-control" name="description[]"></textarea></td>
            <!-- ///////////////////////////// -->
            <!-- change "quantity[]" to quantity[1] and "unit_price[]" to unit_price[1] to use it in js codes -->
            <!-- ///////////////////////////// -->
            <td><input class="form-control line-quantity" name="quantity[1]" type="text" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"></td>
            <td><input class="form-control line-price" name="unit_price[1]" type="text" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"></td>
            <td class="line_vat">£0.00</td>
            <td class="line_total">£0.00</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5" class="text-end">Subtotal</td>
            <td colspan="2" class="subtotal">£0.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5" class="text-end h3">Total</td>
            <td colspan="2" class="total h3">£0.00</td>
        </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
    <a class="btn btn-warning addRow" href="#" id="addRow">Add Line +</a>
    <div class="form-group">
        <br /><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save Quote</button>
    </div>
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

I tried to comment changes in codes, but the **main changes** are using new "blur" calling that mentioned in that question and also separating the event handling for each row by using arrays instead of numbers.

Comment: thanks, that worked great!  Any suggestions to go one step further and add all the line totals together for a grand total at the bottom?